# How can I link a ListView to ModelView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, model-view

I want to create a `ListView` with the names and the codes of the products in my ModelView but when I do:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Product}" />
```

Only the Product Guids are showed.

How could I create a column with the `Product.Name` property and another onew with the `Product.Code` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a GridView. Perhaps like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```